# UIScrollView as subview of another UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to have a small vertical scrollview as subview of another bigger vertical scrollview?

I made a small prototype. When the scrollviews are not hierarchical (if I put them side by side for example), both scroll correctly. But if I put one as a subview of the other, then only the sub scrollview scrolls when I pan it and the top scrollview seems to be locked when I pan it.

I envision that if the user pans the embedded scrollview (subSV in diagram below), then only the embedded scrollview would scroll. Similarly, if the user pans the top scrollview, then only the top scrollview would move and the embedded scrollview may be scrolled out of the visible content.

Do you know of any sample code that does this?

[image: UIScrollView as content of another UIScrollView]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with programmatically but not using StoryBoard. Here is the trivial piece of code:

```
UIScrollView *topSV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 600.0f, 600.0f)];
topSV.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
topSV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000.0f, 2000.0f);

UIScrollView *subSV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
subSV.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
subSV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000.0f, 2000.0f);

[topSV addSubview:subSV];

[self.window addSubview:topSV];
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently is fully supported from 3.0 onwards, and should be automatic (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html). They provide sample code as well, which might contain an example of nested `UIScrollView`s.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Nested subview are indeed supported. However, my prototype using StoryBoard does not seem to work but if I create the subviews programmatically, everything works fine. I'll put the code in an answer.

Comment: Is it possible that you are making both scrollviews subviews of the parent when using Storyboards? I don't think this feature would break by using Interface Builder.

Comment: They are hierarchical (see this screen capture [link](http://mazzaroth.ca/tmp/98375-9342785-234.png)) and have their delegate and outlet defined. I set the scrollview content sizes in `-(void)viewDidLoad` as `_subSv.contentSize  = CGSizeMake(2000.0f, 2000.0f);` and `_topSv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(5000.0f, 5000.0f);`.

Comment: One difference I can spot based on your code, is that you are adding `topSV` to the `window` instead of to the view, as you are doing in the storyboard. Not sure that can cause it not to work though.